# How can I get Scroll Snap working with JS scroll event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on this project where I need both, a scroll listener and scroll-snapping, so I can use a mouse wheel with a horizontal full-screen container that snaps between sections. (When the user scrolls vertically, it scrolls on the X-axis instead.)

I can get both of these to work separately, but not together. When I enable the JS on scroll function it prevents the scroll snapping from working.

I tried everything I know, tried changing other containers' height/overflow properties and tried targeting other elements than body or window. What would be the best workaround be?

The snippet here is adjusted to work with scroll listener at the moment

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.container');

scrollContainer.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;*/
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  /*scroll-snap-align: start;*/
}

#section1 {
  background: red;
}

#section2 {
  background: yellow;
}

#section3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="section1"></section>
    <section id="section2"></section>
    <section id="section3"></section>
  </div>
</html>
```

When i add the following code to enable scroll snap. It stops the wheel event listener from functioning correctly.

```
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Comment: `preventDefault` will, by design, disable `scroll-snap` behavior. Can this just be a listener, or why do you need to manually set `scrollLeft`?

Comment: Hi Bryce, you're correct. The preventDefault stops the scroll snap from working. The line that manually sets the scrollLeft, scrolls the #main container horizontal on the X-axis while the user scrolls vertically with their mouse scroll. The other work around I could think of would be to write some JS code that disables the scroll listener while the scroll snap is working.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is why do you need to control it with javascript?

Comment: Hi Bryce, I believe the only other way to do the horizontal scroll with CSS is to rotate the parent 90 degrees and then the container by -90 degrees. Although this can work it causes some big problems with positioning the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you in a condition where you use scroll-snap-type and want to add functionality like the

```js
window.onWheel = () => {
  // Here will be the body that what functionality you want 

}
```

`onScroll` effect so you can use the `onWheel` event in Javascript